# Не совсем понимаю в чем конкретно ошибка в коде, связано с обработкой событий

Tags: javascript, события, браузер

В теории данный код должен ловить клик на ссылке в контейнере и спрашивать: "Действительно ли человек хочет уйти со странички?" и в случае ответа да, его перенаправлять, иначе нет.

```
           function button_redirect(event) {
               if (event.target.tagName != 'a') {
                   return;
               } else {
                   let r = confirm("Would you really like to leave it?")
                   if (r == true) {
                       continue;
                   } else {
                       event.preventDefault();
                   }
               }
           }
          let links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
          for (var variable of links) {
              variable.addEventListener('click', button_redirect())
```

Comment: еще такой момент, тут вместо continue должно быть что-то другое, поскольку оно выбивает ошибку

Answer (score 2):

В `addEventListener` нужно передавать функцию обработчик, а не результат её вызова

Замените `button_redirect()` на `button_redirect`

Comment: Окей, ошибку учел, но пока все равно не работает(